# GROOVY How to trim a random number into a whole number

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm looking to trim a randomly generated number down to a whole number.

I've tried various means but none seem to work. My latest attempt is as follows:

```
def som = Math.random() * totalContacts
log.info som 
som.toInteger()
log.info som
def cleaned = parseInt(som)
log.info cleaned
```

(I'm logging to the console after each step just to check my results. )

I get the following error when I execute the above code -

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method:
>   Script69.parseInt() is applicable for
>   argument types: (java.lang.Double)
>   values: [44.405365593296] Possible
>   solutions: print(java.lang.Object),
>   print(java.io.PrintWriter),
>   print(java.lang.Object)

Thanks,
 Richard

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that on this line

```
def cleaned = parseInt(som)
```

`som` is a `Double` and there's no `parseInt` method that takes a `Double` argument. You haven't shown your imports, but I guess you've statically imported `Integer.parseInt` and are trying to call that.

The following change should work:

```
def som = Math.random() * totalContacts
log.info som 
som.toInteger()
log.info som
def cleaned = som.toInteger()
log.info cleaned
```

However, it seems like what you're trying to do here is generate a random integer in the range `0..totalContacts` (both inclusive). If so, the following is a simpler solution:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.RandomUtils
import java.util.Random

Integer som = RandomUtils.nextInt(new Random(), totalContacts + 1)
```

Comment: Hi there I ended up getting this to work:

def som = Math.random() * totalContacts
randomSeed = som.toInteger()
log.info randomSeed

But will try your reponse also! 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
def som = Math.random() * totalContacts as int

log.info som
```